# Is it possible to set ARN parameter role_arn in the Java SDK?

Tags: amazon-sqs, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I can access SQS with the following configuration and the AWS CLI:

```
% cat .aws/config
[default]
region = eu-central-1
output = json

[profile dev]
region = eu-central-1
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::<id>:role/<user>
source_profile = default

% cat .aws/credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id = <key>
aws_secret_access_key = <secret_key>

% aws sqs list-queues --profile dev
{
    "QueueUrls": [
        ...
    ]
}
```

I need to specify the `role_arn` parameter to get access to the queues. The problem is that in the AWS Java SDK 2 (version 2.15.69) I couldn't figure out how to set the `role_arn` parameter, at least the  is not automatically loaded. The code I have so far looks like this:

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.SqsClient
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.SendMessageRequest

client = SqsClient.builder().region(Region.EU_CENTRAL_1).build()
req = SendMessageRequest.builder().queueUrl(url).messageBody(msg).build()
client.sendMessage(req)
```

While executing the last line, I get this error message: `Access to the resource https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ is denied.` Basically, it didn't load the `role_arn`. Is it possible to specify the ARN in the Java snippet and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yon must set environment variable `AWS_PROFILE="dev"`.

For now looks to me `default` [aws profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html) is picked by your java code and that `default` aws profile do not have required access rights on the SQS you are trying to access.